# Backlight problems with 12.04 on my Acer Aspire 4736z

Tags: 12.04, acer, backlight

How can I fix a bug that wouldn't let me turn the backlight on after it turns off automatically when I close the lid or when powersave settings kick in?

I also can't adjust the brightness of the screen through the Fn + Left/Right Arrow button combination, how can I make this work?

And one last thing, when I try to follow some of the fixes that are being suggested in forums, like editing the etc/x11/xorg.conf by using the terminal command sudo gedit, the file that I'm supposed to edit is totally blank. And when I look at the folder I didn't see a file "xorg.conf" but I saw "xorg.conf.failsafe" I tried creating a xorg.conf but I can't save the file. What shall I do in this kind of scenario, just in case the solution for my first 2 question requires sudo gedit? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I installed Cairo Dock and there is an applet called Screen Luminosity that lets you use the Fn button for adjusting the brightness.

And I updated Ubuntu this morning and my other problems are gone. I hope this is for good. I'm getting fond of Ubuntu Linux.